# How to get latest 3 months records in presto sql

Tags: sql, presto

I would like to find the frequency of logins of user A within the last 3 months but somehow my date filter in the WHERE clause has some errors.. not sure whether the below is a correct way to retrieve latest 3 months records for presto sql.

```
select userid, count(*)
from user_login
where userid = 3321 and date(from_unixtime(cast(date_login as int)) >= date_add('day',-90,current_date))
group by 1
```

Comment: What is the data type of `date_login`?

Comment: Your date function misses one more ).

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't this work?

```
where date_login > cast(date_add(day, -90, current_date) as timestamp)
```

or:

```
where date_login > cast(current_date - interval '90' day as timestamp)
```

Comment: @adelle . . . You should be able to cast the value as a timestamp.

Comment: I tried and it works. You can avoid the timestamp if your date field is date